# How to check if cell before in the row is the same before adding to the counter

Tags: arrays, excel, with-statement, vba

I'm working on a time sheet which calculates hours in a weekly view per employee. I've implemented some code which determines whether the employee is part of the company yet, on Unpaid leave, are leaving the company, or have already left.

What i'm trying to do is create a table which tells me the number of joiners, leavers and those on unpaid leave by week.

After applying the code to sort my data it looks like this:

[image: Data table]
Where I've replace the random values that existed before with more meaningful descriptions.

I want to create a table which adds to the joiner counter the first time in the row the value is Not Joined' so i don't duplicate the count. For example, ID 1, I don't want to count that person as a joiner in weeks 2 - 5, only in week 2.

This is my code so far I'm looking at rows per column before moving on to the next column:

```
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim Z As Long
Dim Q As Long
Dim Joined As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

'set worksheet to use
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
  'Find last col and row for range
   LastCol = ws.Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
   LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, D).End(xlUp).Row

For I = 3 To LastCol
    NotJoined = 0
        For Z = 4 To LastRow
            'check if cell is > 0
            If ws.Cells(Z, I).Value > 0 Then
                Joined = Joined + 1
            End If
        Next Z
    'Find last row and add value to row below
    Q = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, I).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Cells(Q + 1, I).Value = Joined
Next I
End With
```

How would I add a way to only count a joiner(going from Not Joined to any other value)/leaver (going from any value to x) once in any given row but find these values per week. I am working towards having a table like the below:

[image: Resulting table from data]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done half the job. Please do the rest. This is as far as I got. Paste the code in a standard code module and change the worksheet's name from "Tony" to whatever you are testing on.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nst                            ' Status
    ' 15 Oct 2017
    NstNone = -3
    NstNotJoined
    NstOnLeave
    NstLeft
    NstPresent
End Enum

Enum Nix                            ' Array index
    ' 15 Oct 2017
    NixPresent = 1
    NixJoined
    NixLeft
    NixUnpaid
End Enum

Sub HeadCount()
    ' 15 Oct 2017

    Dim Arr() As Integer                ' Result
    Dim Wk As Long, Ix As Nix           ' Arr() indices
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim StatusArr As Variant
    Dim R As Long, C As Long            ' Row / Column
    Dim Stat As Nst, NewStat As Nst     ' status

    'set worksheet to use
    Set Ws = Sheets("Tony")
    StatusArr = Array(NstNotJoined, NstOnLeave, NstLeft, NstPresent)

    With Ws
        ' prefix a period to refer to object in With statement
        LastCol = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim Arr(1 To (LastCol - 3), 1 To NixUnpaid)

        For R = 4 To LastRow
            Stat = NstNone                  ' unable to determine changes in Wk 1
            For C = 4 To LastCol
                Wk = C - 3
                NewStat = StatusArr(Application.Match(Val(.Cells(R, C).Value), StatusArr, 1) - 1)
                If NewStat <> Stat Then     ' count changes
                    ' Count joiners
                    If (Stat = NstNotJoined) And (NewStat = NstPresent) Then
                        Arr(Wk, NixJoined) = Arr(Wk, NixJoined) + 1
                    End If
                    ' count leavers
                    If (Stat <> NstLeft) And (NewStat = NstLeft) Then
                        Arr(Wk, NixLeft) = Arr(Wk, NixLeft) + 1
                    End If
                End If

                Stat = NewStat
                If Stat = NstOnLeave Then Arr(Wk, NixUnpaid) = Arr(Wk, NixUnpaid) + 1
                If Stat = NstPresent Then Arr(Wk, NixPresent) = Arr(Wk, NixPresent) + 1
            Next C
        Next R

        .Cells(20, "D").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
    End With
End Sub
```

I introduced the following logic to your records.

1. -2 means "Not yet joined"
2. -1 means "On leave" (presumably unpaid)
3. 0 or blank means "not working" (presumably left)
4. Any other positive number represents working hours (presumed to be working)

Please use these numbers on the worksheet instead of the texts you presently have. If need be, code could be written to translate them. In the code, these numbers are represented in Enum Nst. `NstNone` is used at the start of the week. I think your system is flawed at that point because you can't tell how many people joined or left without knowing the previous status. `NstNone` bridges the gap.

The last line of code determines that the output will be written in the range D20:H23 of the same sheet on which the data are found. Existing data will be over-written. Be sure to write nothing in column A below the employee IDs because the macro uses column A to determine how many employees to evaluate.

The result will have as many columns as you have weeks above. It will have 4 rows as determined by Enum Nix, meaning employees present, joined, left and on unpaid leave. The idea is that you would paste this list into a table where you have the captions and formatting you want. You can change the sequence by modifying the Enum Nix. Just be sure to assign the value `= 1` to the first name. (And do not shuffle Enum Nst!)

My numbers don't match those in your result. That is because I didn't understand your result. However, I think the numbers are there, and if you need additional ones they will be easy to integrate into the established system.